# creating external ActionListener using MVC

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, actionlistener

Actionlistener, doesn't work, nothing happens when the  `joptionpane` should popup on `crear_Arbitro` click.
having trouble creating an external ActionListener class for diferent JPanels inside a JFrame, the idea is to make some  Jpanels  which will then be inserted into a JFrame  using JTabbedPane, and learning to use the MVC  architectural pattern to create a GUI, here is a brief example of the code for  what i'm trying to do:

controller:

```
public class Controlador_Universal {

   public VentanaPrincipal_vista ventanaPrincipalVista;
   public Arbitros_modelo arbitrosModelo;
   public ArbitrosListener ArbitrosListener;

    public Controlador_Universal() {
        ventanaPrincipalVista = new VentanaPrincipal_vista();
        ArbitrosListener ArbitrosListener = new ArbitrosListener();
        ventanaPrincipalVista.pestañaArbitros.crear_Arbitro.addActionListener(ArbitrosListener);
    }
```

Listener:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import modelo.Arbitros_modelo;
import controlador.Controlador_Universal;

public class ArbitrosListener extends Controlador_Universal implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == super.ventanaPrincipalVista.pestañaArbitros.crear_Arbitro) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Presionó en crear Arbitro");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you are having trouble, but you haven't explained what the trouble is.

Comment: @Takendarkk,  you're right,  i've edited; the problem is that  the ActionListener  `ArbitrosListener`  isn't being recognized

Answer (score 1):

Follow the naming contentions. Don't use `_` underscores in class- or variable names. Variable names should start with a lower case letter, and preferably, should **not** contain special characters (this can really be blöd...)

Concerning the problem: With

```
ArbitrosListener ArbitrosListener = new ArbitrosListener();
```

you are creating a new instance of your `ArbitrosListener` listener class. Although the class extends the `Controlador_Universal` class, the *instance* that you are creating there is a **new** one. So the query

```
if(e.getSource() == super.ventanaPrincipalVista.pestañaArbitros.crear_Arbitro)
```

can never be `true`: The `getSource` method returns the `crear_Arbitro` of the instance that the action listener was added to, but this is a different one than that of the action listener itself.

Based on the current code, you don't even need this check. And particularly, you may **not** let your action listener extend the `Controlador_Universal` class. Based on the current code, you could just write

```
public class ArbitrosListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Presionó en crear Arbitro");
    }
}
```

and this should already work. When you have multiple buttons, you could omit the `ArbitrosListener` class, and instead use anonymous listeners, like this

```
ventanaPrincipalVista.pestañaArbitros.crear_Arbitro.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Presionó en crear Arbitro");
    }
});
```

However, all this seems somewhat unrelated to MVC, so you should possibly point out more clearly how this is related to a model, a view and a controller.

Comment: thanks, yes  well its related to a MCV because:
-1 every panel  will  be created in seperate classes
-2 there will be a Main window which will contain all the panels
-3 there is a back end side of the GUI, which connects to a DB using JDBC
-4 the controller that  I showed  above  will  relate  all the `MainWindow.Panel.object.addActionListener` and well since this is such a big class I was thinking of creating the ActionListener classes for  each  Panel  separately  so that the controller uses the  ActionListener Classes, and the code won't be that big  inside the controller.